# How do you select a max of one column and not NA's in another column in R?

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way in R where I can select the max(col1) where col2 is not NA?

Example datafame named df1

```
#df1
Year  col1  col2 
2016   4     NA  # has NA
2016   2     NA  # has NA
2016   1     3  # this is the max for 2016
2017   3     NA
2017   2     3   # this is the max for 2017
2017   1     3
2018   2     4   # this is the max for 2018
2018   1     NA
```

I would like the new dataset to only return

```
Year  col1  col2 
2016   1     3
2017   2     3
2018   2     4
```

If any one can help, it would be very appreciated?

Comment: Why not two rows for `Year == 2017`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Looking at the max of `col1`, not `col2`.

Comment: @Gregor Got it, I had the impression that it was `max(clo2)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% filter(!is.na(col2)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  arrange(desc(col1)) %>%
  slice(1)
```

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
df1[!is.na(col2), .SD[which.max(col1)], by = Year]
```

---

This works in a fresh R session:

```
library(data.table)
dt = fread("Year  col1  col2 
2016   4     NA
2016   2     NA
2016   1     3
2017   3     NA
2017   2     3
2017   1     3
2018   2     4
2018   1     NA")

dt[!is.na(col2), .SD[which.max(col1)], by = Year]
#    Year col1 col2
# 1: 2016    1    3
# 2: 2017    2    3
# 3: 2018    2    4
```

Comment: I get a unused argument error when using data.table.

Comment: I get a unused argument error when using data.table. I prefer to use data.table since I'm already using this library already in my previous code. @gregor

Comment: Not sure why, I just posted a fully working example. Can you (a) verify my reproducible example works for you in a fresh R session, and (b) if it still doesn't work on your actual data, share a reproducible example showing that?

Comment: finally made it work.  I had to convert my data.fame into a data.table before this worked. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yeah, that's what `setDT(df1)` does in my `data.table` version of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In `base R`

```
out <- na.omit(df1)
merge(aggregate(col1 ~ Year, out, max), out) # thanks to Rui
#  Year col1 col2
#1 2016    1    3
#2 2017    2    3
#3 2018    2    4
```